# log incoming message twilio node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio

I have this basic function that sends a message back to the user who sent a message to my Twilio number.

So if the number `1234567890` sends my twilio number a message, it shoots a message back to `1234567890`. However, I want to be able to log what the user sends to me. So if they send me `hi`, then I can use that to query my db and send them a message back.

Here's my function:

```
app.post('/sms', (req, res) => {
const twiml = new MessagingResponse();

twiml.message('The Robots are coming! Head for the hills!');

res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'});
res.end(twiml.toString());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It looks like you are using Node.js and Express to receive the incoming webhook from Twilio. [When Twilio sends this webhook it includes a number of parameters that describe the message you received](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/guides/webhook-request). The request is made in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format, so you will need to set Express up to parse those parameters from the body of the request. You can do that with the built in [Express `urlencoded` middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.urlencoded):

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded());
```

Once you are parsing the request successfully, you can read out the parameters from `req.body`. For example, the number that sent the message will be `req.body.From` and the body of the message will be `req.body.Body`. For example:

```js
app.post('/sms', (req, res) => {
  const { Body, From } = request.body;
  console.log(`Message from: ${From}: ${Body}`);

  const twiml = new MessagingResponse();

  twiml.message('The Robots are coming! Head for the hills!');

  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'});
  res.end(twiml.toString());
});
```